# Bootstrap Navbar is split in the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar that is split in two due to a dropdown menu that I attempted to create. How do I go about closing that gap/split? Here is a link of what it [looks like.](https://ibb.co/qxWZKq2)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Navigation Bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-custom fixed-top">
  <div class="container px-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Welcome</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
      <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='dropbutton'>Games</button>
        <div class='dropdown-content'>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#game1">BlockBuster: The Game</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#game2">One Night Ultimate Werewolf</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#game3">Herd Mentality</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#game4">Scrawl</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#game5">Pinch ‘n’ Pass</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Review">Leave us a Comment!</a></li>
        <form id="form">
          <input type="search" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Searching Games">
          <button class='button-search button1'>Search</button>
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Please see if you can edit the snippet above to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially a few things causing it but the exact nature of the error is not clear on your demo link. I have assumed that all of your menu items are supposed to be on the left with just the search bar on the right?

If so, quite a few of the Class values are wrong. Try starting with changing all the #game1 to #game5 classes to dropdown-item instead of nav-item.

Above and beyond that, the button for your dropdown and the dropdown itself should be inside a UL. So yes, you would end up with a UL then inside it the Games button and another UL containing your dropdown items.

Like this, each dropdown is it's own list and they are all contained inside the *navbar-nav* list....

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink1" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            MainButton1
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu fade-down" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="link1a">Button1a</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="link1b">Button1b</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="link1c">Button1c</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Main Button 2
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu fade-down" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink2">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="link2a">Button2a</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="link2b">Button2b</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```